# Clone elements of a list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a Python list that looks like this:

```
list = [ a, b, c, d]
```

I am looking for the most efficient way performanse wise to get this:

```
list = [ a, a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, d ]
```

So if the list is N elements long then the first element is cloned N-1 times, the second element N-2 times, and so forth...the last element is cloned N-N times or 0 times. Any suggestions on how to do this efficiently on large lists.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Perhaps there's a better solution for what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: the version that I put up was pretty much pyfunc's solution. I think that he probably deserves to get the accepted answer and maybe he can edit my minor improvements into his for reference.

Comment: @aaronasterling Did just that...and thanks for the detailed answer (to u and all the guys)...I am developing a CLONALG AIS algorithm and I need this behaviour for my cloning function...much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this - A simple one

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> t = []
>>> lenList = len(x)
>>> for l in range(0, lenList):
...     t.extend([x[l]] * (lenList - l))
... 

>>> t
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that I am testing speed, not correctness. If someone wants to edit in a unit test, I'll get around to it.

```
pyfunc_fastest: 152.58769989 usecs
pyfunc_local_extend: 154.679298401 usecs
pyfunc_iadd: 158.183312416 usecs
pyfunc_xrange: 162.234091759 usecs
pyfunc: 166.495800018 usecs
Ignacio: 238.87629509 usecs
Ishpeck: 311.713695526 usecs
FabrizioM: 456.708812714 usecs
JohnKugleman: 519.239497185 usecs
Bwmat: 1309.29429531 usecs
```

Test code [here](https://gist.github.com/718629). The second revision is trash because I was rushing to get everybody tested that posted after my first batch of tests. These timings are for the fifth revision of the code.

Here's the fastest version that I was able to get.

```
def pyfunc_fastest(x):
    t = []
    lenList = len(x)
    extend = t.extend
    for l in xrange(0, lenList):
        extend([x[l]] * (lenList - l))
```

Oddly, a version that I modified to avoid indexing into the list by using `enumerate` ran slower than the original.

Comment: This is surprising! I have usually noted that simple approach tends to be good but I am amazed by the range of time of various solutions. Your effort is commendable for none of us have actually posted the timings. I can't up vote because I have exhausted my votes for today.

Comment: That's pretty awesome.  How'bout a test for memory footprint?

Comment: heh, I didn't expect it to be that slow. I guess using extend() and the like is way better due to it being compiled c code

Comment: @ishpeck. I don't know a good way to test memory foot print. Do you know of one?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> [item for i, item in enumerate(items) for j in xrange(len(items) - i)]
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

First we use `enumerate` to pull out both indexes and values at the same time. Then we use a nested for loop to iterate over each item a decreasing number of times. (Notice that the variable `j` is never used. It is junk.)

This should be near optimal, with minimal memory usage thanks to the use of the `enumerate` and `xrange` generators.

Answer (score 2):

Lazy mode:

```
import itertools

l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux']

for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(e, len(l) - i)
    for i, e in enumerate(l)):
  print i
```

Just shove it through `list()` if you really do need a list instead.

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(e, len(l) - i)
  for i, e in enumerate(l)))
```

Answer (score 2):

My first instinct..

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
nl = []

i = 0

while len(l[i:])>0:
    nl.extend( [l[i]]*len(l[i:]) )
    i+=1

print nl
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in using repeat from itertools

```
from itertools import repeat

alist = "a b c d".split()
print [ x  for idx, value in enumerate(alist) for x in repeat(value, len(alist) - idx) ]

>>>['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator: it's O(1) memory and O(N^2) cpu, unlike any solution that produces the final list which uses O(N^2) memory *and* cpu. This means it'll be massively faster as soon as the input list is large enough that the constructed list fills memory and swapping starts. It's unlikely you need to have the final list in memory unless this is homework.

```
def triangle(seq):
    for i, x in enumerate(seq):
        for _ in xrange(len(seq) - i - 1):
            yield x
```

Answer (score 0):

To create that new list, `list = [ a, a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, d ]` would require O(4n) = O(n) time since for every n elements, you are creating 4n elements in the second array.  aaronasterling gives that linear solution.

You could cheat and just not create the new list.  Simply, get the index value as input.  Divide the index value by 4.  Use the result as the index value of the original list.

In pseudocode:

```
function getElement(int i)
{
     int trueIndex = i / 4;
     return list[trueIndex]; // Note: that integer division will lead us to the correct index in the original array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fwiw:

```
>>> lst = list('abcd')
>>> [i for i, j in zip(lst, range(len(lst), 0, -1)) for _ in range(j)]
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def gen_indices(list_length):
    for index in range(list_length):
        for _ in range(list_length - index):
            yield index

new_list = [list[i] for i in gen_indices(len(list))]
```

untested but I think it'll work